# How to vibrate Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, vibration

This question is about how to access control of vibrating your windows phone 8.1 on some event using c++. I have also answered the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First import the following two namespaces:

```
using namespace Windows::Phone::Devices::Notification;

using namespace Windows::Foundation;
```

Then use a function like this:

```
void PlatformInterop::vibrateDevice(int duration)
        {
            VibrationDevice^ vib = VibrationDevice::GetDefault();
            if (vib != nullptr)
            {
                TimeSpan time;  
                // Convert from milliseconds to  1.0e-7 of a second, and limit to 5 seconds
                time.Duration = min(duration*10000, 50000000);
                vib->Vibrate(time);
            }
        }
```

This is all you need to do.

Comment: Your units do not add up: if `time.Duration` really takes nanoseconds, you need `5000000000` instead of `50000000` (9 zeroes instead of 7); and you need to multiply your `duration` integer by `1000000`.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the error, but actually I mentioned it wrong in the  comment. Actually, the function takes arguments in the unit of 1.0e-7 seconds. I have tested it and it works for me.